# Videos freeze in fullscreen mode in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, video-player, html5

When I maximize a flash OR HTML5 video, e.g. on youtube, the picture freezes but the video continues to play. I can still hear the sound and even see the mouse cursor switching from normal cursor to hand cursor when I hover over the position where a control button should be but the whole chrome window becomes unresponsive.
The video is played fine if I don't enter fullscreen mode. That affects both flash and HTML5 videos.

How can I solve this issue?

System:
Ubuntu 14.04
Google Chrome Stable 37.0.2062.120-1 
Nvidia-331 331.38-0ubuntu7.1

Comment: How did you install Chrome, and have you tried it without extensions settings etc?

Comment: Also, do any errors appear when you run Chrome in terminal, and you try full-screening the video(s)?

Comment: nope, no errors whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, people have found [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1593274) helpful.
However it didn't work for me, so I troubleshooted for a bit, and figured that it must be some clash between the kernel handling my discrete video card(Nvidia GeForce 630m) , which however seems to be fixed by installing and running [tlp](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-tlp-0-6-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-and-derivative-systems/). Added bonus, more battery life :) :)

Comment: Thanks for this. It fixed the random freezing of html5 video on my Thinkpad X1 Carbon 3rd Gen when trying to leave the fullscreen mode

Answer (score 2):

Disable **HW acceleration** in Firefox and Chrome/Chromium. Today's Google-Chrome update fixed the issue for me but *before that*, **disabling** the hardware acceleration was what fixed the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Forgot to mention. I also change this layers.gpu-process.enabled to false in about:config

Comment: Worked for me. Is there a fix for this instead of a work around? Meaning that I would like to keep using hardware acceleration while having full screen working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Type `about:config` in FireFox address bar, accept the risk warning. in the `about:config` search bar type:

```
media.hardware-video-decoding.force-enabled;
```

Set it to `true`

Also change:

```
media.hardware-video-decoding.failed;
```

Set it to `false`

Comment: Could you explain please why this is expected to help?

Answer (score 0):

[a post on the google chrome help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Ef6ZqIqAnI4) suggests that resetting the browser zoom (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>) works around this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uncheck the hardware acceleration.... Do this instead:

In the menu, click on Tools ==> option

Then in General, find the following:

Digital Rights Management (DRM) Content

UNCHECK IT... That's it.