# google chrome on chromium freeze while play video full screen on facebook

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, crash

while i play a video on my Ubuntu 15.10 in chrome or chromium in full screen mode at moment i use ctrl+tab or volume up or exit from full screen will freeze and i can do any thing even logout or anything.

my laptop model is E550 lenovo.

Comment: see [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/731409/86380).

Comment: If this happens and you want to shut your machine down safely, press CTRL+ALT+F1, login with your username/password, type `sudo reboot`, and type your password again.